# Lebesgue integral gap point

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

> Calculate integral $ \int_0^{100} (1+2x)^2 d\mu_F(x) $ where $$ F = \left\{
> \begin{array}{l}
> {0}, \ x < 0\\
> {1 - cos(x) }, \ x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2}),\\
> {2} , \ x \ge \frac{\pi}{2}
> \end{array}
> \right.$$

My solution is to of cource divide the integral into two parts (of which only the part related to $[0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ will remain). The integral then can be represented as $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} (1 + 2x)^2 F^{'}(x) dx $ that equals $4\pi - 3$. The question is should I also consider the gap point $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and add $(1 + 2\frac{\pi}{2})^2 \times F(\frac{\pi}{2})$ to my answer? I would also be grateful for a formal algorithm for such tasks.

Comment: As single points have measure zero, the integral on the interval $[0,\pi/2)$ is equal to the integral on $[0,\pi/2]$. But if you calculated the Riemann integral correctly, then you should have already taken this into account.

Comment: @NDewolf , single points indeed have measure zero in case of continious measure. But I'm pretty sure that in gap points the measure is equal to the size of the gap, but that is exactly what I want to clarify. If you can provide me with a source that proves me wrong, I'd gladly read it.

Comment: So the function to integrate is zero everywhere outside the interval. And using the property that Riemann integrals do not change if you integrate over an open or closed interval, you can simply integrate it.

Comment: The integral of piecewise defined functions is just defined as the sum over all domains.

Comment: @NDewolf I'm sorry if I'm not getting your point, but this integral is not Riemann's. It is a Lebesgue's integral part of which can be calculated as Riemann's.

Comment: @NDewolf I have no trouble calculating the Riemann's part. Gap points is the trouble I'm facing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59920/discussion-between-youtur-and-ndewolf).

Comment: $\mu_F\bigl(\bigl\{\frac{\pi}{2}\bigr\}\bigr) = \lim_{n\to \infty} F(\pi/2) - F(\pi/2 - 1/n)$. The weight is not $F(\pi/2)$ but the height of the jump of $F$ there.